# how to read a php error message into a string variable

Tags: php

I'm doing a small program which needs to read error meesage when errors occur.

For example, one operation triggered an error, and php log recorded it as:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Smarty error: [in /mnt/n2my_web/templates/ja_JP/mail/reservation_create.t.txt line 16]: syntax error: mismatched tag {/if}. (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 2338) in /mnt/n2my_web/lib/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1092
```

I know by setting **ini_set('display_errors', '1');** the error message can be printed. But I need to read it, in order to format it.

By which means can I achieve this? Any answer is appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you want to know about errors in general or the specific case of fatal errors, which are a whole different issue and cannot be treated like normal errors?

Comment: Hi Mike, actually errors in this project will always be smarty error, that is to say all the errors should be php fatal errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the only way to can access any error information around a fatal error is to use `register_shutdown_function()` to try to catch these errors and work with them before the script is terminated.  This is not 100% reliable.

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
   $last_error = error_get_last();
   if(!is_null($last_error) && $last_error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
       /*
       Do something with $last_error info.
       $last_error will contain array with keys as follows:
       ['type']['message']['file']['line']
       */
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mike, my script terminated at calling a smarty function. So I placed **register_shutdown_function()** just 1 line before calling smarty function it seems doesn't work. Then I put it at the beginning of my own function, also doesn't work. Where to register should be a question?

Comment: Mike, your answer is right, but I guess unless **ini_set('display_errors', '1');** is set, or error message will not be returned. I'm not sure, in my practice if the **display_errors** is not set I cannot get the message from **error_get_last();**

Answer (score 2):

Use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php , to handling error, I recommend you to just use custom exception and error handler

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Worth noting that `error_get_last()` won't be any good for anything more severe than an `E_WARN` since execution halts at that point.

Comment: Hi egig, thanks for your recommendation. As for this question, as Sammitch said terminating point should be considered. I think it's my express causes confusions, thank you.